# automatically request permissions on demand

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions, cordova-android

I'm trying to wrap an existing, working PWA application as a Cordova application so that I can publish it via Play Store.

The application makes use of camera, microphone, GPS and similar. As such, I've added the necessary `uses-permission` tags in the Android Manifest file.

After installing the debug APK, the system lists these potential permissions in the App settings screen as expected, however does not automatically grant any of these permissions (I'm aware this is intentional).

When running my PWA inside Chrome, the browser asks the user for permission **automatically** (on demand), for example when calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`.

Is such an *automatic* mechanism possible with Cordova or do I absolutely need to add code to my application which *explicitly* requests permission at runtime?

NB: These permissions are *not* vital for the application (meaning that I don't want to request all of them *upon startup*) but there are numerous places in the application where a permission dialog would be necessary and locating all relevant routines would be laborious/error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request all these permissions at run time because those permissions are dangerous permissions.

Please declare only necessary permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml